# Zomato reviews, Post API?

Tags: web

I am collecting required information for a restaurant through a web page. While collecting the review I am using Facebook single sign on and would like to autheticate Zomato and post reviews directly on Zomato.
Anyone has the experience of doing it?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, questions asking about whole APIs, their usage and opinions on them are off-topic here. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Hi Shree! Unfortunately, Zomato doesn't offer content creation APIs to third-party developers just as yet.